# Regex - Match Specific Character Anywhere

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match against a string that is a mix of letters and special characters.

ex:

```
THIS!IS*A STRING
```

I've tried to put together a (probably noobish) regex that does this for the characters I want (Java):

```
"\\w{1,40}&*-*\\.*`*\\(*\\)*\\/*\\\\*!*,*\\** *"
```

It seems to work but only when the special character is at the end of the line. Is there a way to match it regardless of position?

EDIT1:

Spec:

Characters allowed are: `A-Z a-z 0-9 – . ‘ ) ( & / \ ! , * space`.

EDIT2:

Getting closer I think:

```
"[\\w-.`()&/\\!,* ]+"
```

Seems to be giving me what I want but when I add a range I get an exception:

```
"[\\w{1,40}-.`()&/\\!,* ]+"
thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character   range near index 10
[\w{1,40}-.`()&/\!,* ]+
          ^
```

Comment: Add `.*` at the end of the pattern to match "anything till the end of string"

Comment: This is a improvement but it doesn't work if one of the characters I want to allow is at the start of the string.

Comment: Then please specify in the question what exactly you want to match, because your regex is too complicated to be meaningful.

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit about what you are trying to do, exactly?

Comment: From the first sentence of the question I'd start with the simplest regex, like `"[\\w.!*]+"`

Comment: Added the spec for what I want to allow.

Comment: But do you want to match whole string or extract words specified as in your question, separated with spaces?

Comment: The objective is so match characters inside the string rather than words.

So the characters mentioned above (as well as a-z. A-Z, 0-9) can appear anywhere multiple times but the @ character is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I have achieved it by...

The hyphen is a range char and needs to be at the start or end of the character class.

I shifted the range outside the character class and this looks to have fixed the issue of it being ignored if it's inside a character class.

```
"[\\w.`()&/\\!,* -]{1,40}+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```
    String s = "THIS!IS*A STRING";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w{1,40}&*-*\\.*`*\\(*\\)*\\/*\\\\*!*,*\\** *");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

The results are:

```
    THIS!
    IS*
    A 
    STRING
```

If you want to use String.matches, you should extend the pattern to match whole strings.

```
   String s = "THIS!IS*A STRING";
   System.out.println(s.matches("(\\w{1,40}&*-*\\.*`*\\(*\\)*\\/*\\\\*!*,*\\** *)*"));
   // -> true
```

Comment: Hi, is compile significant?

I was doing this before:

    if(s.matches(p){
    true;
    }
    else{
    false;
    }

Comment: @RegexNoob Compile is not significant. 　It is important to use which method.